# Cannot set effect transition in FFmpeg

Tags: android, image, video, ffmpeg, effect

Im using FFmpeg to create a video from some image .
This is my command:

```
val command = "-framerate 1/3 -i $photo1Path -framerate 1/3 -i $photo2Path -framerate 1/3 -i $photo3Path -i $mp3File -filter_complex \"[0:v]scale=w=min(1080\\,iw):h=min(1080\\,ih):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,fade=t=out:st=2:d=1[0v];[1:v]scale=w=min(1080\\,iw):h=min(1080\\,ih):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[1v];[2:v]scale=w=min(1080\\,iw):h=min(1080\\,ih):force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease[2v];[0v][1v][2v]concat=n=3:v=1:a=0[v]\" -map 3:a -map \"[v]\" -shortest -c:v libx264 -b:v 5000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -movflags +faststart $outputFilePath2"
```

I want to add effect between each image, but it's not work. I have consulted quite a few sources, such as [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg/834035#834035)

About version FFmpeg, Im using

```
implementation 'com.arthenica:mobile-ffmpeg-full-gpl:4.3.1'
```

Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because , as explained by the ffmpeg tag: Only questions about programmatic use of the FFmpeg libraries, API, or tools are on topic. Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my self.

In above command, I can't set effect transition because it contain '-framerate 1/3' field.

This field mean set fps for the image = 1/3 per second (it mean 1 frame in 3 second). Therefore, it's not enough frame for effect transition (like fade=in, fade=out)

The simple way to solve this is replace '-framerate 1/3' with '-loop 1 -t 3'